# HTTP health checks failing when using HEAD /serverup.html

Tags: haproxy

I need to health check backend servers with HEAD request by looking for /serverup.html file and expect 200 status

I tried using "option httpchk HEAD /serverup" and "http-check expect status 200"

> frontend test1
>
> > mode http
> >
> > bind 192.168.100.1:80
> >
> > default_backend test1
>
> backend test1
>
> > description Test Webpage
> >
> > balance leastconn
> >
> > mode http
> >
> > option httpchk /serverup
> >
> > http-check expect status 200
> >
> > server webserver1 192.168.100.101:80 check inter 3s fall 3 rise 5 downinter 1m
> >
> > server webserver2 192.168.100.102:80 check inter 3s fall 3 rise 5 downinter 1m
> >
> > server webserver3 192.168.100.103:80 check inter 3s fall 3 rise 5 downinter 1m
> >
> > server webserver4 192.168.100.104:80 check inter 3s fall 3 rise 5 downinter 1m

Answer (score 0):

some servers requires also the host header.

can you try the following line for the check

```
option httpchk HEAD /serverup\n\rHost: your-backend-http-hostname\n\r\n\r
```